# WordPress Tag or Custom Taxonomy Return All Posts if has that Word in Post Title

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop, taxonomy, pre-get-posts

Note : In this question "Tag" means Tag or a Custom Taxonomy (Assume that it is topic).

It is hard to explain my question with words. So I will explain it using following example.

> When user visit example.com/tag/google/ or example.com/topic/google/
>   should be out all posts which has 'google' word in title.

I am going to use `pre_get_posts` action to change the loop. But I have no any idea how to modify the loop. I could not find any thing in [WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) documentation also.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you are on a tag page with a conditional, and then modify the main query:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_the_title', 1 );
function search_the_title($query){
    // Check if it's the main query
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin()) {
        // If it's a tag page, search posts by tag
        if ( is_tag() ) { 
            $query->set('s' , get_query_var('tag' , ''));
            // Unset the current tag to search all posts
            unset( $query->query['tag'] );
            return;
        }
        // If it's a taxonomy page, search by taxonomy value
        if ( is_tax('topic') ){
            $query->set('s' , get_query_var('topic' , ''));
            // Unset the current taxonomy to search all posts
            unset( $query->query['tax_query'] );
            return;
        }
    }
}
```